# Entity Frameworks get non entity object from stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework 6.

I want to run a stored procedure that returns a non entity object (3 colunms per row)

```
using(var dbContext = new DBContextEntity())
{
    var queryProducts = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DataTable>("dbo.GetProductByDesc @q", query);                
}
```

How to get that data as `DataSet` or anonymous object that I can iterate that?

Comment: Just create a class for your result, then you can do `SqlQuery<MySpResult>(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know EntityFramework does not provide anonymous object materialization. The reason for that is that it probably generates IL code for each type and caches it (or just does a plain PropertyInfo caching).

The solution is to just create a simple class with properties you need matching the names of the stored procedure result set and use this class as a generic parameter for SqlQuery.

Edit:

SqlQuery implements IEnumerable and when you iterate over it, it executes automatically in thge current thread. To iterate the result you can for example:

```
foreach(var product in queryProducts)
{
   // do something with each product here
}
```

You can also pass a list of product class instances to a function expecting it:

```
ShowProducts(queryProducts.ToList());
```

You can also make the query run in background and return you a list of Product after it has finished, more information about asynchronous fetching can be found [here: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/performing-asynchronous-operations-using-entity-framework.htm](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/performing-asynchronous-operations-using-entity-framework.htm)

Comment: And how do I iterate it?

Comment: I just edited my answer with more info on iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Too said, it is best to define a POCO class with properties corresponding to the field names and datatypes returned by the StoredProcedure or other SQL statement.

It is generally better to avoid the use of DataSets in any new development work you are doing.  They do have their uses but have a performance penalty in high throughput scenarios which the POCO's clearly avoid.

If the attraction for DataSets is the ability to easily serialize the data over the wire or to a file for later use, then the various serialization frameworks will help you with that eg DataContractSerializer, Newtonsoft.Json, etc.

This also allows for portability if the POCO is defined in a PCL (Portable Class Library).

If you must use DataSets, I would rather use typed DataSets.  The DataRow's can be used as the POCO in @Too's answer, since they have a default constructor.  Just be careful of nulls and their unique treatment in fields other than String.